# How to access attribute in jquery for a parent element undefined in firefox?

Tags: jquery

HTML looks like this (using angular):

```
<div fruit="pear">
<a onclick="clickHander($event)"></a>
</div>
```

I want to access the "fruit" attribute in the parent.
I tried:

```
var clickHandler = function(event) {
var fruit = $(event.target).parent().attr("fruit")
}
```

This works in chrome but not in Firefox as it says undefined. How do I get around this?

Comment: Don't make up your own attributes. Instead use [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) like `data-fruit="pear"`.

Comment: Also, where do you imagine `$event` comes from?

Comment: When I use data-fruit in my code, it appears "fruit" is undefined. $event comes from angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it like following ( using **[JQuery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** ) :

**HTML :**

```
<div data-fruit="pear">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var fruit = $(this).parent().data("fruit");
});
```

Comment: Wow, they support it since 5 years and I haven't heard about it... Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div data-fruit="pear">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var fruit = $(this).parent().attr("data-fruit");
});
```